# Prevent quotes from being escaped in Play templates

Tags: playframework-2.0, playframework-2.6

I'm trying to generate some javascript with a play framework template and I can't seem to find a way to output the contents of a string without quotes being escaped. I'd read that `@Html()` is supposed to do raw output, but it seems it's only for preventing entities from being encoded.

A test template:

```
@(code: String)

// plain injection
@code

// Html injection
@Html(code)
```

The output being generated:

```
// plain injection
var foo=\"bar\";

// Html injection
var foo=\"bar\";
```

It seems that quotes are escaped either way.

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure that the quotes in your string are not escaped? I tried reproducing your problem and got different results.

With plain "printing" (`@code`) i got

`var foo = &quot;bar&qout;`

With Html wrapping it worked for me:

`var foo = "bar"`